# Add clickable text in read only buffer?

Tags: text-properties, hyperlinks, read-only-mode

If i have a writable buffer, i can use this to insert hyperlink.

```
(require 'button)
(insert-button "foo" 'action (lambda (x) (find-file "~/test.py")))
```

But i have to add `clickable text` property to a piece of text in read only buffer. I am trying this

```
(add-text-properties
 1
 50
 '(lambda (x) (find-file "~/test.py")))
```

But it is throwing this error

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Odd length text property list")
```

Any suggestion to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you did not use the correct format to add a text property.

quote from [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Properties.html):

> **Function: add-text-properties start end props &optional object**
>
> The argument props specifies which properties to add. It should have the form of a property list (see Property Lists): a list whose elements include the property names followed alternately by the corresponding values.

However, for your specific problem, emacs has a different command:
[emacs lisp manual excerpt](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Making-Buttons.html)

> The following functions add a button using an overlay (see Overlays) to hold the button properties:
> **Function: make-button beg end &rest properties**
>
> This makes a button from beg to end in the current buffer, and returns it.

If you insist on doing it via text properties, see above link for

> **Function: make-text-button beg end &rest properties**

Example code for specific problem:

```
(make-button 1 50 'action (lambda(x) (find-file "~/test.py")))
```

Comment: Welcome.  This answer would be even better giving the correct code in this particular context.

Comment: code example added